Google Maps blue gps dot
I have question about Google Maps blue gps dot that shows location and direction on map.
How can we replace the direction arrow with a shining blue beam like in Android Google Maps app?
I'm wondering if this allows setting in maps or not.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/tribune.com.pk/story/1186417/google-maps-replaces-direction-arrow-favour-blue-beam%3famp=1
In one app I saw that the behavior of the beam is exactly the same as in Google Maps. App name is Circuit can download app and check.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.underwood.route_optimiser

That is a custom location icon that uses the device gyroscope to change its direction. You would turn off the default one and implement your own
